# How do I use a kernel module built for a different kernel version?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, kernel

I have a .ko file and nvme.h file which was built on a kernel version 3.17 and I am trying to copy this .ko file to a machine which has ubuntu 14.04 with kernel version 3.19. I also copied the nvme.h file

When I try to do rmmod nvme after copying the .ko file, it gives an error saying no nvme module is currently loaded. 
I had a backup of the original .ko and nvme.h file and when I copy that back and run the rmmod nvme, it works just fine. I need to use the updated .ko and nvme.h files. Any pointers will be helpful? How can I port this over to 3.19 successfully. Please suggest.

Comment: You need to build kernel modules for each new kernel. You can't copy binaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Each module is compiled for a specific kernel version, and can't be used for kernels that differ from that.

You'll need to either get a `.ko` file for the specific kernel you're running there, or recompile it for that kernel yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. But if the versions differs too much (between trees for example), probably it will taint the kernel, or won't find some symbol.

You must patch the module if modprobe -f does not work.

https://github.com/D1W0U/ARP-RootKit/blob/master/patch-lkm.py